# Am getting unterminated comment error on scratchpad

Tags: javascript

I just start learning programming today so sorry if the question is simple. I took a tutorial in **codeAcademy** and am doing the same thing there as I am on scratchpad.

```
console.log('hello');
```

> Exception: SyntaxError: unterminated comment

when I define the variable as a string I get this

```
console.log(text: string 'hello');
```

> Exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

If you could recommend a good tutorial that would be great. 
Thanks.

Is    console.log('hello');    correct then?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do with `console.log(text: string 'hello');`, it's not "defining the variable as a string".

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JavaScript syntax.  It looks like you're trying to say:

```
console.log('hello');
```

There is no real notion of static typing in JavaScript, so I'm not sure where the `:string` came from (unless you're learning TypeScript).

Best of luck!